# Inequality $\tau_3(uv)\leq \tau_3(u)\tau_3(v)$ for ternary divisor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Consider ternary divisor function $\tau_3:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{R}_{\geq}0$ defined as $$\tau_3(n)=\#\{(a,b,c)\in \mathbb{N}^3:abc=n\}.$$

I know that $\tau_3$ is multiplicative function, i.e. $\tau_3(mn)=\tau_3(m)\tau_3(n)$ for $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Also one can show that $$\tau_3(p^{\alpha})=\frac{(\alpha+1)(\alpha+2)}{2}.$$

I was wondering how to show that $\tau_3(uv)\leq \tau_3(u)\tau_3(v)$ for any $u,v\in \mathbb{N}$?
Can anyone show the proof please.

Comment: Reduce to the case $u$, $v$ powers of the same prime $p$, and apply your formula.  Then use multiplicativity.

Comment: @orangeskid, do you mean $u=p^{\alpha}$ and $v=p^{\beta}$?

Comment: @orangeskid, I've checked and in this case it is true and you do not need to use multiplicativity since $\tau_3(uv)=\tau_3(p^{\alpha+\beta})=\frac{(\alpha+\beta+2)(\alpha+\beta+1)}{2}$ and $\tau_3(u)\tau_3(v)=\tau_3(p^{\alpha})\tau_3(p^{\beta})=\frac{(\alpha+2)(\alpha+1)(\beta+2)(\beta+1)}{4}$. Boring computation shows that that $\tau_3(uv)\leq \tau_3(u)\tau_3(v)$.

Comment: You would use multiplicativity after that, to prove for arbitrary $u$, $v$.  ... I wonder where is $\tau_3$ used...

Comment: @orangeskid, is something bothering you in the above comment?

Comment: @orangeskid, I was wondering can you show the proof for general $u$ and $v$? It would be nice to see it!

Comment: @orangeskid, the general case looks confusing to me.

Comment: Just wrote a sketch of the proof, hope it helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\tau_3$ is multiplicative

$$ \tau_3(n) = \prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}}\frac{(\nu_p(n)+2)(\nu_p(n)+1)}{2} $$
hence in order to show that $\tau_3(uv)\leq \tau_3(u)\tau_3(v)$ it is enough to show that
$$\frac{(\nu_p(u)+\nu_p(v)+2)(\nu_p(u)+\nu_p(v)+1)}{2}\leq \frac{(\nu_p(u)+2)(\nu_p(u)+1)}{2}\cdot\frac{(\nu_p(v)+2)(\nu_p(v)+1)}{2}$$
or
$$ 2(A+B+2)(A+B+1) \leq (A+2)(A+1)(B+2)(B+1) $$
or
$$ AB(AB+3A+3B+5)\geq 0 $$
which is fairly trivial over $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: We know that $$\tau_3(uv)=\prod\limits_{p\mid uv}\dfrac{(\nu_p(uv)+2)(\nu_p(uv)+1)}{2},$$ $$\tau_3(u)=\prod\limits_{p\mid u}\dfrac{(\nu_p(u)+2)(\nu_p(u)+1)}{2}$$ and $$\tau_3(v)=\prod\limits_{p\mid v}\dfrac{(\nu_p(v)+2)(\nu_p(v)+1)}{2}.$$ Of course I know the fact that $\nu_p(uv)=\nu_p(u)+\nu_p(v)$. You said that it is enough to show that $$\dfrac{(\nu_p(uv)+2)(\nu_p(uv)+1)}{2}\leq\dfrac{(\nu_p(u)+2)(\nu_p(u)+1)}{2}\cdot \dfrac{(\nu_p(v)+2)(\nu_p(v)+1)}{2}.$$

Comment: But this step should be clarified. I mean we need to know how many terms we have in product in $\prod \limits_{p\mid uv}$ and in $\prod \limits_{p\mid u}\times \prod \limits_{p\mid v}$.

Comment: It is enough to take the product over all the primes. From some point on we will just have $\nu_p(u)=\nu_p(v)=0$.

Comment: I did not get your point.

Comment: $$ n = \prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}} p^{\nu_p(n)} $$ $$ m = \prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}} p^{\nu_p(m)} $$ $$nm=\prod_{p\in\mathcal{P}} p^{\nu_p(n)+\nu_p(m)} $$ It does not matter to count $\omega(n), \omega(m)$ or $\omega(nm)$.

Comment: 1) In the post I guess you meant "which is trivially true over $\mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$. 2) What is $\omega()$?

Comment: $0$ is already an element of $\mathbb{N}$, according to the convention I am used to. $\omega(n)$ is the number of prime factors of $n$.

Comment: I think that I get it now! Thank you so much for your help! +1

Comment: In all these infinite products over $p\in \mathbb{P}$ only finitely many are not equal to $1$. I guess one should clarify what do we mean by infinite product over primes even in this case. RIght?

Answer (score 0):

1. First show for $u$, $v$ powers of the same prime $p$.
2. Now consider arbitrary $u$, $v$. Then

$$u = \prod_p u_p,  \ \ v = \prod_p v_p$$

decompose each into a product of powers of distinct primes. Note that  we have  $(uv)_p = u_p v_p$

Therefore

$$\tau_3(uv) =(\tau_3 \textrm{ multiplicative}) \prod_p \tau_3 ((u v)_p) = \prod_p \tau_3 ( u_p v_p) \le \prod_p (\tau_3( u_p ) \cdot \tau_3 (v_p)) = \prod_p \tau_3(u_p) \cdot \prod_p \tau_3(v_p) = \tau_3(u) \cdot \tau_3(v)$$

The inequality $\tau_3 ( u_p v_p) \le \prod_p (\tau_3( u_p )$ is true since $u_p$, $v_p$ are both powers of $p$, and we showed 1.

Note: we also have the inequality $\tau_2 (uv) \le \tau_2(u) \tau_2(v)$. Probably it works for all $\tau_k$.

Comment: The notation $u_p$ is a bit confusing. What do you mean by $(uv)_p=u_pv_p$?

Comment: $u_p$ is the $p$ part in the prime decomposition of $u$

Answer (score 0):

*Lemma*. Any two factorizations of an integer $n$ have a common refinement. In other words, if we have factorizations $n=x_1\cdots x_r$ and $n=y_1\cdots y_s$ there are $z_{ij}\,$ ($\small 1\le i\le r,1\le j\le s$) for which

$$ \begin{array}{c|ccc}
& x_1 & \cdots & x_r \\ \hline
y_1 & z_{11} & \cdots & z_{1r} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
y_s & z_{s1} & \cdots & z_{sr}
\end{array} $$

(Interpret this as saying the product of the $z_{ij}$s along any column gives the $x_j$ above it or along any row gives the $y_i$ left of it.) I leave it as an exercise to verify the $2\times 2$ case, and the $s\times r$ case follows by induction.

---

Define $T_3(n)=\{(a,b,c)\mid abc=n\}$, so $\tau_3(n)=|T_3(n)|$.

There is a surjection $T_3(u)\times T_3(v)\to T_3(uv)$ given by

$$ \big(\,(a_1,b_1,c_1),\,(a_2,b_2,c_2)\,\big)\mapsto (a_1a_2,b_1b_2,c_1c_2). $$

We can see it is onto, by applying the lemma to the equations $uv=abc$.

This implies $|T_3(u)||T_3(v)|\ge|T_3(uv)|$, or $\tau_3(uv)\le\tau_3(u)\tau_3(v)$.